# angular directive data binding and interaction with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm really confused with the following concept and hope someone can clear it up for me. Consider the following template code:

```
<test-dir val="val"></test-dir>
```

Assume test-dir has the following isolated scope:

```
scope:{ val : '='}
```

My understanding that this achieves a 2-way binding between the $scope.val variable inside the `test-dir` directive and the global variable `$scope.val`. So if I change the value of either one, the other one would be affected.

However, consider now I have the following template code:

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, val) in values">
  <test-dir index="index" val="val"></test-dir>
</div>
```

and the following isolated scope:

```
scope:{
  index:'=', 
  val : '='
}
```

Suddenly `index` and `val` are no longer 2-way bound. So each one of my `test-dir` directive has its own `index` and `val`, and changing the variables locally won't effect anyone else. Why?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` [creates new child scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#angular-scope-inheritance), so each `test-dir` having its own `index` and `val` is working as intended.